# Ubuntu 16.04 Failed to start Create Static Device Nodes in /dev

Tags: boot, 16.04, systemd

I have an issue that prevents me from booting up. See below screenshot. As soon as I log in the below appears for a fraction of a second and then returns to sign on.

It appears to be related to systemctl status: systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service?

Any ideas on how to fix this? I keep having to restore an old clean /dev/sda2 partition every time it happens and it seems to be intermittent?
Many thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One possible cause of this issue is a root folder that is owned by a user account.

After booting, open a terminal and do this:

```
sudo stat -c "%U %G" /
```

You *should* see:

```
root root
```

If you see anything else, then it's wrong and you'll need to:

```
sudo chown root:root /
```

Note that there is no `-R` in there. Do not `-R` with this operation. Bad things will happen.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot !- I did indeed have UNKNOWN root - now it has root root as you indicated. Do you think this will prevent it from re-occuring now? If it does can I do this operation from a terminal in a live USB ? I have upvoted your answer

Comment: Yes, this *should* solve your problem going forward. The question — if this happens again — is what or who is changing the ownership of `/`. Hopefully you’ll never need to ask the question.